# MultiChoiseModeListener methods are never called

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I have ListView with custom adapter. In activity `onCreate()` method I set `ListView` choice mode to `MULTIPLE_CHOISE_MODAL` and provide it with `MultiChoiseModeListener` implementation I wrote. The problem is listener methods never get called, except the constructor. Long-clicking just triggers listview item `onClick()` method, instead of triggering `onCreateActionMode` or anything.

I tried using `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead of my custom adapter and using `simple_list_item_1` instead if my item layout, has not helped much, methods are still silent.

So, can anybody provide any ideas what can be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I have no idea why this happens, but if `View` of the item in your `ListView` is clickable the selection will not work. To fix the problem I had to use `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`in my `ListActivity` instead of separate listeners for each item. Hope this helps somebody